# How to associate featured image of my blogger's post as thumbnails in my website

Tags: blogger, google-blogger-api

I want to associate my blogs post in my website which i have been able to do using Blogger API v3.0.
I am able to call the post's title, content and comments, but i want to retrieve the images i have uploaded in my content as a thumbnail.
Code i have used so far

```
<script>
    function handlePost(response) {
        document.getElementById("blogTitle").innerHTML += "<h3>" + response.title + "</h3>";
        document.getElementById("blogContent").innerHTML += "<p>" + response.content + "</p>";
    }
    function handleComment(response) {
        for (i in response.items) {
          document.getElementById("blogComments").innerHTML += "<p>" + response.items[i].content + "</p>";
          document.getElementById("blogComments").innerHTML += "<span>" + response.items[i].author.displayName + "</span>";
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOGID/posts/POSTID/?callback=handlePost&key=APIKEY"></script>
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOGID/posts/POSTID/comments?callback=handleComment&key=APIKEY"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the url param `fetchImages=true`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOGID/posts/POSTID/?callback=handlePost&key=APIKEY&fetchImages=true
```

you will get response like

```
"title": "Posts title",
"content": "content of the post",
"images": [{
  "url": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/image.jpeg"
}]
```

then you can retrieve the image for example like this

```js
var postImage = response.images[0].url;
```